# Transparency when drawing in CGContext does not work Swift

Tags: swift, draw, alpha, cgcontext

Hello i'm developing a drawing application. I try to draw multiple lines with transparency in a context (one line over another) but the transparencies do not work as I thought they work when drawing one image over another. I've made this test with 2 squares:

```
var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)
self.addSubview(imageView)

/* CREATE A SQUARE UIImage */
let color:UIColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.40, blue:0.21, alpha:1.0)
let bounds:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0.0)
var ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
ctx?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
ctx?.fill(bounds)
let rectangleUIImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

/* DRAW SCUARE WHIT ALPHA 1 */
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
ctx?.setAlpha(1.0)
ctx?.draw(rectangleUIImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

/* DRAW 10 SQUARES WHIT ALPHA 0.1 IN THE SAME PLACE */
ctx?.setAlpha(0.1)
for i in 0..<10 { 
  ctx?.draw(rectangleUIImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 200, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
 }


imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

I would expect the above code to result in this:[Two boxes visually with the same transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXUs2.png)

But no matter how many times I draw a transparent square on another I always find this :( :
[Two boxes, one without transparency and one with transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9acR.png)

Comment: It would probably help if you get the new context after the second call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`.

Comment: Many thanks but I get the same result :(